# Login with Instagram in IONIC 3 mobile app

Tags: ionic3, instagram-api

I want to implement login with instagram in my IONIC 3 Application.

So is there any plugin available for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there is a plugin for corodva in ionic:

```
Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-instagram-plugin
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/instagram@4
```

Also you can try auth0 to autentificate:
Install

```
# installation with npm
npm install auth0-js @auth0/cordova --save

# installation with yarn
yarn add auth0-js @auth0/cordova
```

Code:

```
// src/App.js

var Auth0 = require('auth0-js');
var Auth0Cordova = require('@auth0/cordova');

function getBySelector(arg) {
  return document.querySelector(arg);
}

function getById(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function getRedirectUrl() {
  var returnTo = env.PACKAGE_ID + '://YOUR_DOMAIN/cordova/' + env.PACKAGE_ID + '/callback';
  var url = 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/v2/logout?client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&returnTo=' + returnTo;
  return url;
}
```

See also [here](https://auth0.com/authenticate/cordova/instagram/)
Hope this helps you to go on.